# Callbacks with parameter from subclass

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, oop, callback

I have some problems with one of my TypeSript functions. I hope this is not an absolutely stupid question, but I believe what I am trying to do should work in theory.

Here is a simplified version of my problem. I hope it shows where the problem occurs (the original has way too much code).

```
abstract class A {
    name: string;

    log(callback: (ev: A) => void) {}

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    addr: string;

    constructor(addr: string, name: string) {
        super(name);
        this.addr = addr;
    }
}

let b = new B("1", "2");

b.log((ev: B) => {});
```

The problem occurs in the last line of the code. The `log` function is a callback with the type `A`. And I want to call it with an attribute of type `B`. In theory, this should work, because `B extends A`. But it shows the following error:

```
Argument of type '(ev: B) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(ev: A) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'ev' and 'ev' are incompatible.
    Property 'addr' is missing in type 'A' but required in type 'B'.(2345)
input.tsx(13, 5): 'addr' is declared here.
```

I don't want to cast my `ev` parameter in the function. I hope you get where the problem is and what my goals are.

Have a nice day.

Comment: What exactly do you want with a method that takes a callback and supplies to it the object itself? Presumably if you can call the method you already have a reference to the object. You can just call `b((_: any) => console.log(b.addr))` if you want. It seems a bit redundant for the object to take a callback that will be called with the same object. Unless it's *not* the same one but a different instance of the same class but then it still seems odd to call `instance1.log((thisWillBeInstance2 => {})`.

Comment: "*In theory, this should work, because B extends A*" - no. It is allowed for the `log` method to pass a `B` instance instead of an `A` one, but it is not allowed for the callback to declare that it only accepts `B` instances not any `A`. Please show us the actual implementation of `log` so we can recommend the proper approach to type it.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct error and has to do with **contravariance**.

If you would have `log` having parameter of type `A`, defined as:

```typescript
abstract class A {
    // ...
    log(ev: A) { console.log(ev.name) };
    //...
}
```

You could call that function from:

```typescript
let b = new B("1", "2");
b.log(b); // works fine, because `B` also has property `name`
```

You have full example [here](https://tsplay.dev/Nn69xN).

But when passing full function `(ev: A) => void`, it is not contravariant with `(ev: B) => void`. For example, function that satisfies the signature `(ev: B) => void` could be following:

```typescript
function (ev: B) {
    console.log(ev.addr); // B specific, input parameter of type A would break!
}
```

This function would break if you pass `ev` of type `A` inside, because `A` does not contain property `addr`, only `B`. That's why typescript does not let you do that.

Comment: I want to call the function passed to `log` as a callback. If I change the parameter of `log` to an object instead of a function it is not a callback anymore. So it has to be a function.

Comment: You missed the point - valid signature for your `log` callback on both classes is `(ev: A) => void`. Then you can pass your `B` instance into it, in your `B` implementation.